# Bivariate Random variables and chips problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Problem:** Three chips are selected at random without replacement from a box
containing three red chips, two white chips and four black chips. Let $X$ and $Y$
be the number of red chips and the number of white chips respectively.

**Thoughts:**
I am having difficulty finding a general formula for this sort of probability mass function $ f$.

For instance the probability that $x=0,y=0$ (i.e. $3$ black chips) seems to be
$f(0,0)= {4 \choose 3} (4/9)(3/8)(2/7)  / {9 \choose 3}$ whereas the probability that $x=1,y=0$ is $f(1,0)= {3 \choose 1} (3/9) {4 \choose 2} (4/8)(3/7) / {9 \choose 3}$. Any hints on how to express this generally much appreciated.

Comment: @BruceET does that usually need replacement?

Comment: You should look for multi-hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @JamesDickens: Right. Thanks for correction. Getting late...misread problem.

Comment: @BruceET is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so clearly this is an example of the multivariate hypergeometric distribution,  so that it is given by:

$$P(X=x, Y=y) = f(x,y) = \frac { {3 \choose x} {2 \choose y} {4 \choose 3-(x+y)}} {9 \choose 3},$$
where $x=0,1,2,3$,  $y=0,1,2$ and $0 \leq x + y \leq 3 $.